# File I/O in Kotlin with (potentially) unknown encoding

Tags: kotlin, io, character-encoding

This is my first attempt to learn and use Kotlin. I have a simple task: read a file line by line, preprocess each line and put a specific portion into a map. Each line is tab-separated.

When trying to preprocess, things start going horribly wrong. I tried to debug, and instead of the *normal* characters, this is what I can see:

[image: screenshot from IntelliJ IDEA debugger]

In between every two adjacent readable characters, there is the strange-looking block with horizontal lines.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
fun mapUserToId(path: String): MutableMap<String, Int> {
    val user2id = mutableMapOf<String, Int>()
    val bufferedReader = File(path).bufferedReader()
    bufferedReader.useLines { lines ->
        lines.drop(1).forEach { // dropping the first line with column headers
            val components: List<String> = it.trim().split("\t") // split by tab delimiter
            val user: String = components[2]
            println(user.length) // length is nearly double due to the strange block-like characters
            val id: String = components[3]
            user2id[user] = id.toInt() // fails due to number format exception, because of those block-like characters
        }
    }
    return user2id
}
```

This looks like a charset issue, but I can't figure out what the charset could be, and how to specify that charset in the above code. Opening the file in `vim` looks perfectly normal (as in, one would suspect that this file has UTF-8 encoding).

Comment: vim is likely to try several different encodings until it finds one that looks valid; so loading in vim doesn't necessarily indicate a particular encoding.  You can see what vim decided by typing `:set fenc`.  (As per Chthonic Project's answer, I'd guess it's actually UTF_16, and that the strange characters you saw were from `\0` bytes.)

Answer (score 1):

This is, indeed, an encoding issue. The problem is resolved by specifying the encoding while creating the buffered reader as follows:

```
val bufferedReader: BufferedReader = File(path).bufferedReader(Charsets.UTF_16)
```